# Graphite Clustered Webapp - Not Sharing Data

Tags: monitoring, cluster, metrics, graphite

I have Graphite setup on three instances on EC2:

- carbon-relay - `relay1.graphite.prod.example.ec2`
- carbon-cache + webapp - `cache3.graphite.prod.example.ec2`
- carbon-cache + webapp - `cache4.graphite.prod.example.ec2`

The relay is working perfectly with consistent-hashing. The problem is the two web servers are not communicating with each other, so I only see the metrics from one server.

I spent a lot of time looking at https://answers.launchpad.net/graphite/+question/114206 and I can't figure out what I have setup incorrectly. I can run a wget from cache3 against cache4, get data back and see it in the Apache logs. So I don't think it's a firewall issue. I tried enabling `suppressError = False` in remote_storage.py and turned on DEBUG in local_settings.py, but I don't see any errors in Firebug.

**cache3 - local_settings.py**

```
CLUSTER_SERVERS = [ 'cache4.graphite.prod.example.ec2', 'localhost' ]
```

**cache4 - local_settings.py**

```
CLUSTER_SERVERS = [ 'cache3.graphite.prod.example.ec2', 'localhost' ]
```

I have tried using IP addresses as well and that had no impact.

I did a little more debugging and modified `storage.py` to directly hard code my remote hosts:

```
STORE = Store(settings.DATA_DIRS, remote_hosts=["cache4.graphite.prod.example.ec2", "127.0.0.1"])
```

That worked. So, somehow my `CLUSTER_SERVERS` value isn't getting pulled in from local_settings.py correctly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the permissions on `local_settings.py` were too restrictive and Apache was unable to read it:

```
-rw------- 1 root root  4006 May  4 13:40 local_settings.py
```

Fixing the permissions to 644 (instead of 600) resolved the problem.